# System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker has text too much streched

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker in my software. But the text appears to be too much stretched in the selected date shown in the textbox of the DateTimePicker control. See screenshot below:

[image]

Is there any way to condense / tighten the text? Or is there any other control I can use to select date in my form? And can I increase the font of the text in the calendar? it seems not to be changed when I change the font size property of the text in the textbox of the calendar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Answer (score -2):

Increase the height and width of div than give calender height, width and its font size.